# Configuration does not exsit in the current context C# blazor App

Tags: c#, blazor-server-side

I am using blazor server app and following a tutorial and get stuck in this line of code:

```
services.AddDbContext<AppDBContext>(item => item.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("myconn")));
```

Configuration is not found. Despite i have added

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
```

Do i miss anything? The automatic resolution saying that to install Fluent Assertions

Comment: `Configuration` isn't a namespace, it's the name of a variable or field in your code. I suspect you copied this from an example or snippet that stores a reference to `IConfiguration` in a variable or field named `Configuration`

Comment: I am follwoing this https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/blazor-crud-app-using-entity-framework-core-in-net-5/

Comment: Any reason you don't use the official Blazor, ASP.NET Core or EF Core Getting Started docs? That's not the only problematic article on that site. Besides, both Blazor and EF have changed *drastically* since .NET 5 so may of the things in that article no longer apply

Comment: In any case that article's code is completely broken and will result in unexpected bugs. The official Blazor docs explicitly warn about lifetime of scoped objects like DbContext in Blazor - it's the entire user session. Worse, by wrapping a low-level CRUD non-service over a high level ORM, the code completely breaks transactions. That `Insert` can easily execute 34 DELETEs that were left over from a previous page.

Answer (score 0):

Just do

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
services.AddDbContext<AppDBContext>(item => item.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("myconn")));
```

Instead of

```
services.AddDbContext<AppDBContext>(item => item.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("myconn")));
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**